# How to access to Base DataContext property in C# code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

I have got a class that gaves me a list of images with two URL addresses as property, one for thumbnail and second for full image. In XAML code of different class I successfully bound to those thumbnail data and showed thumbnails of images. Although now I wanna work with second property in C# code after click on thumbnail and I don't know how to access to DataContext. Thank you for a help.

> http://s30.postimg.org/ecx7qepnl/prb2.png

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific / show code? To me, it looks like you only need to do `img.DataContext` according to your screenshot.

Comment: I may add some code but I think this is what I excatly need but I just don't know how I can use in my code that Image1024 property.

Comment: oh.. Then you need to use cast the datacontext as dkozl suggested. You can read about casting [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in debugger [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) is set to instance of `MyPlaces.FlickrImage` so all you need to do is get the value of `img.DataContext` and cast it to your type:

```
var flickrImage = img.DataContext as MyPlaces.FlickrImage;
if (flickrImage != null)
{
    // do something with flickrImage.Image1024
}
```